# Second MySQL database PHP from WordPress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am building a new WP site and want to create a couple of pages that access data from a separate mysql database. I want to insert the PHP into the pages using a plugin like Insert PHP.

I've installed the plugin but, I cannot seem to get the database to connect from within the WP page.

First off, I am not even sure where to put the second mysql file on the same server. It has a different login and PW than the WP site.

Should I put it in the \var\www\html folder? I don't want to replace the DB I am using, just send some queries out to another one on the same server to get some data.

I've added PHP with the insert PHP plugin and I get an access denied message:

Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Here is the code I use:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "xxxx";
$password = "xxxx";
$dbname = "xxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Please help and TY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe your root password is incorrect. Try this one 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 0):

PHP is executing the script so looks like your MySQL user or password is wrong. Considering you are using 'root' which is a security concern, I would suggest you create a new user for that database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I realize the root login is a bad idea. I actually did not create the database. I am resurrecting it from an old site build and that's how the user set it up. I am pretty certain I have the login and PW correct in the code. 

I am also wondering about the location of the .sql file. Where do you recommend putting it?

Comment: @user2267031 you can't just put the .sql file somewhere and open it with php. You need to import it into mysql first using mysqladmin or mysql command line before you can use it.
Note that a sql file this doesn't include users / permissions

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help. Here is my solution.

You can pull data from a second mysql database and display it on a WP page. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 so I needed to the the LAMP install. Be sure to give mysql a password when you install it during the LAMP installation.

Then once wordpress is up and running, install a plugin called PHP Insert as mentioned. The above code worked just fine using the mysql PW assigned at the time of installation. I was able to connect and now I will be spending eternity deciphering the old PHP left for me to rewrite. Happy times!

Answer (score 0):

After I imported the sql database into the new mysql server, the correct pw to use was from the new server. I also created a second account so I am not logging in with root anymore.  Now I can connect. TY.